# Template class specialization using class as type for the specialization

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, specialization

I'm currently working on a program with C++ 14; basically I was implementing a template class called Database and i wanted to differentiate the constructor of this template class basing it on different specialization of my template. In other words i wanted it to do different things when I specialize my type with a specific class. in my example I wanted to do different things when i pass the class boat to it (boat is define by a constructor with 5 strings).
'''

```
#include"boat.h"
   #include<vector>
  #include<iostream>
   #include<string>
   #include<fstream>
   using namespace std;



template <typename T>
class Database{


public:
    Database(const string& file_name);
    ~Database();
    void Add (const string& file_list);
    void Upload (const string& file_list);
     vector <T>  get_vector();
protected:
    vector <T> _list;
    vector <T>_new_element;
    string token,st;
    string delimiter=";";
    size_t pos=0;
    vector <string> temp;
    fstream f;
    int max_id;

};

template <>
class Database<boat>
{
friend class boat;
public:
    Database(const string& file_name){
        f.open(file_name);
        //controllo apertura file
        if (f.is_open()) {
            while ((getline(f, token))) {

                while ((pos = token.find(delimiter)) != (string::npos)) {
                    st = token.substr(0, pos);
                    tempg.push_back(st);
                    token.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
                }
                tempg.push_back(token);
                _list.push_back(boat(tempg[0],tempg[1],tempg[2],tempg[3],tempg[4]));
                pos = 0;
                tempg.clear();
            }
        }
    };
    ~Database();
    void Add (const string& file_list);
    void Upload (const string& file_list);
    const vector <boat>  get_vector();
protected:
    vector <boat> _list;
    boat _new_element();
    string token,st;
    string delimiter=";";
    size_t pos=0;
    vector <string> tempg;
    ifstream f;

};'''
```

So basically I did this method with the constructor to open a file and read the important data of the class boat which were divided by ';'.

My question is: how i have to define the syntax for the template constructor specialization, when I pass to the template not a normal type like `int`, `char` or other, but when I pass a class. Because it give me the error:

> boat was not declared in this scope class Database.

How do I declare it right?

Comment: You don't specialize constructor here, you specialized whole class

Comment: You may want to check, vector indeed contains 5 elements before accessing any of the indices. As for the error you get: How should we be able to tell, why this error occurs? You're not showing the declaration after all. All I notice is the suspicious lack of a header guard/pragma once which may or may not be an error depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethimng like this:

```cpp
template<>
Database<boat>::Database(const string& file_name)
{
    // ... your stuff here ...
}
```

But I think that the more correct design is to have template implementation of the constructor and then have stream input and output operartors for the class `boat`, i.e.

```cpp
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, boat& obj)
{
   // ... actual input here ...
   return is;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const boat& obj)
{
   // ... actual output here ...
   return os;
}
```

and then use them to load/store data in the file.

Comment: Ty for the operator tips, i think you are absolutely right, is better load and read with the operators.  For the specialization, i'll try the next days with that method to see if it is going to work... Ty!!